# Why MySQL call from python reports SQL error?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Whenever I try to create a table and run the code in python

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","ayman","1234","Students")

cursor = db.cursor()

query = """CREATE TABLE STUDENT_DETAILS (
            ID INT.
            NAME CHAR(50), 
            EMAIL CHAR(10) )"""

cursor.execute(query)
db.close()
```

I get this result:

```
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.\n\t\t\tNAME CHAR(50), \n\t\t\tEMAIL CHAR(10) )' at line 2")
```

What might be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the query:

```py
query = """CREATE TABLE STUDENT_DETAILS ( ID INT. NAME CHAR(50), EMAIL CHAR(10) )"""
```

This might work:

```py
query = """CREATE TABLE student_details(id INT, name CHAR(50), email CHAR(10));"""
```

Comment: yes, thank you done.   the problem was in ID INT.    I should make it like this ID INT,

Comment: Happy to help :)